# How to decompose N into A and B so that A and B are close to each other.

Tags: factoring

I would like to decompose $N$ into $A$ and $B$ so that $A$ and $B$ are close to each other. Even I would allow some small error. Se I would like to have:

$$N = A*B + \epsilon_N$$

where

$$\epsilon_N < A, \epsilon_N < B$$

and I would like to minimise

$$|A - B|$$

The underling application is to find number of rows and columns for N elements so that the matrix is as close to square as possible.

Comment: Is this to be done on a computer? You could take the floor of $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: @EricKightley The problem I see with your idea is if $N = k^2-1$ for some $k\gg 1$, then we'll have $\epsilon_N = k^2 -1 -(k-1)^2 = 2k$. So your solution is great if the only assumption is $\epsilon_N <A$, but if you want to maintain $\epsilon_N$ "small" this could be problematic.

Comment: Yeah, on a computer. The problem with floor of $\sqrt{N}$ is that I want to minimise the difference not the error.  With floor of $\sqrt{N}$ for $N=24$ I will get (6,4). However, round of $\sqrt{N}$ works quite well. Thanks.